# Heroku using Meteor settings.json On Launch

Tags: heroku, meteor

I've configured a heroku environment variable by using:

```
heroku config:set METEOR_SETTINGS="$(cat settings.json)"
```

However, the app fails to launch, and heroku's logs state:

```
Error: METEOR_SETTINGS are not valid JSON: $(cat settings.json)
```

Thinking it's not finding my settings.json file. This seems to be the approach I've seen others take. I've tried looking for the root of my app by using

```
heroku run bash
```

And changing directories looking for the settings file, and I cannot find it.
It sits in the root directory of my local repository as settings.json

I'm using the following buildpack: https://github.com/jordansissel/heroku-buildpack-meteor.git

Comment: Where is your settings.json file in your project?

Comment: It sits in the root directory of my local repository as settings.json

Comment: Try this notation: METEOR_SETTINGS="`cat settings.json`" (http://pastebin.com/6qC91t23) since SO formats the "`" symbol

Comment: Same: Error: METEOR_SETTINGS are not valid JSON: 'cat settings.json'

I'd really like to know where exactly the app root is when i bash into my heroku instance and 'cd' around looking for it. I can't find it at all.